# Interpretation of a definition of 'incidental'

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives

[image]

A BOOK REFERRED TO.

The Concise Oxford Dictionary (COD).

I have a predicament of making out the definition. Allow me to put forward my interpretations. **Incidental images, colours** are the imaginary appearances we make up which are temporary and likely far away from the real identities. Am I under a misapprehension?

Comment: [***incidental colour***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22incidental+colour+Colour+occurring%22) *- Colour occurring in nature which has no functional purpose in contrast to **functional colour** serving, for example, in certain animals and plants as a means of camouflage, courtship or mimicry.* It's essentially a domain-specific usage.

Comment: Thank you so much. I misinterpreted that. i.e., as false images which are able to relate to the notion (Don't judge a book by its cover).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**Incidental**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incidental) means

> adjective
>
> 1 Happening as a minor accompaniment to something else.
>   ‘for the fieldworker who deals with real problems, paperwork is incidental’
>   ‘incidental expenses’
>
> 1.1 Occurring by chance in connection with something else.
>   ‘the incidental catch of dolphins in the pursuit of tuna’
>
> 2 *incidental to* Happening as a result of (an activity)
>   ‘the ordinary risks incidental to a fireman's job’
>
> (Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Another source defines [**incidental**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/incidental) as

> less important than the thing something is connected with or part of:
>   *Try not to be distracted by incidental details.* 
>   *The points you make are true, but they're incidental to the main problem*
>
> (Cambridge Dictionary)

The Collins COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary defines [**incidental**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/incidental) as

> If one thing is incidental to another, it is less important than the other thing or is not a major part of it.
>   *The playing of music proved to be incidental to the main business of the evening.*

Also, [**incidental**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/incidental_1) can be described as

> 1. related to something but considered less important: 
>      *an incidental observation*; 
>      *incidental expenses (=small costs connected with an activity): You will receive an allowance for meals and incidental expenses.* incidental to: *Information skills are not merely incidental to the curriculum but central to it.*
> 2. accidentally happening as a result of an activity or process:
>      *incidental damage*
>
> (MacMillan Dictionary)

While I'm reluctant to criticize the COD, checking the Google ngram for ["incidental images, incidental colours"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incidental%20images%2Cincidental%20colours&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincidental%20images%3B%2Cc0) (with and without the "u" in colors) shows few *incidents* of the use of "incidental images" and amazingly no use of "incidental colours" within their corpus of books. (However, Clare notes below that she found instances of *incidental colors* in Google books.)

The original poster, *equanimity*, Googled it himself and discovered [**this definition**](http://192.184.80.244/ned0/is/7629237791.pdf):

> Incidental images, colours : such as are perceived by the eye as a consequence of visual impressions no longer present.

and further notes in his comments:

> "It seems to be like that. I gaze at a thing in the bright fluorescent lighting of a room, closing my eyes to see an incidental image."

This statement is perfectly valid based on the definition cited.

Comment: There's instances of *incidental colors* In Google  books.

Comment: Thank you all. I googled it. http://192.184.80.244/ned0/is/7629237791.pdf  (Incidental images, colours : such as are perceived by the eye as a consequence of visual impressions no longer present.)

Comment: It seems to be like that. I gaze at a thing in the bright fluorescent lighting of a room, closing my eyes to see an incidental image.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include your comments. Thank you for the additional information.